# How can i load the page with the chatbox closed?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this Chat box http://packetcode.com/apps/facebook-like-chat/ and I would like to minimize the Chat Box (Orange) when the page loads. Can anyone help, please?

The source code can be found here https://github.com/shaadomanthra/facebook-like-chat

Thanks in advance,

Comment: $(function(){
if (!$('.msg_wrap').is(:visible)) {
     $('.msg_wrap').hide();
     $('.msg_box').hide();
}
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS thats faster then script and will fire directly,

```
.chat_body {
    display: none;
}
```

If you look in the DOM after klicking on the chat-box this is what hapens.

or inline css/style on the element:

```
style="display: none"
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for the **orange** one, use:

```
$(function(){
    $('.chat_body').hide();
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the script needs to wait for the DOM to load before it can run the script. CSS is direct, and will work when the page is renderd.